# Getting paths to code of imported modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to analyse some python file. For this I should analyse all modules (i.e. get source code of this modules if they written on Python) imported in given file.

How I can get paths to files with imported python-modules?

I try to use `sys.path`, but it gives all paths, where does python interpreter *may* search modules

Comment: Read about `sys.modules` and `inspect.getsource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. I tried some things and the problem is that many standard modules seem quite inaccessible, like the `math` module isn't even Python, but a C library (.so file). If you only need to access user-defined modules and not standard ones, something like this could get you files and source:

```
import inspect
import sys

def main():
    # sys.modules contains a mapping between module names and module
    # objects, but many more than the one imported in a file. dir()
    # returns a list of names available to the local scope (also variables
    # functions etc.). Combine those two and you get the modules available
    # to the local scope
    modules = [sys.modules[i] for i in dir() if i in sys.modules]
    files = []
    code = []
    for module in modules:
        try:
            # modules may have a __file__ attribute
            files.append(module.__file__)
            # get's you the actual code
            code.append(inspect.getsource(module))
        except:
            pass
    print(files, code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`__file__` is not defined for all standard modules and `inspect.getsource()` doesn't work for them either, that's why the `try-except` block, but for non-standard modules this could get you started.

Answer (score 2):

For the 3rd party modules, following should print the file path.

```
module_file = <module_name>.__file__
```

You can then print the file contents.

Answer (score -1):

Modules are found in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` in unix-like systems
and are found in `C:\Python34\Lib` in windows

Comment: Not always, not by a long shot.